# How can I set a webcam to automatically take pictures and FTP them?

Tags: ftp, webcam

Does anyone know of a way that I can configure a webcam to automatically take a picture every few seconds and send that to a site via FTP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some free ones:

- [Webcamfirst](http://www.webcamfirst.com/)
- [Yet Another WebCAM software](http://www.yawcam.com/)
- [Fwink](http://www.lundie.ca/fwink/)

I've used Webcamfirst with good results, but I used the email functionality. They all list FTP functionality.

This for a website I presume?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest program to use is Motion.  To install:

```
apt-get install motion
```

The config file is in `/etc/motion/motion.conf`

Very easy to setup/configure.
I would then use `ncftpput` (part of `ncftp`) to upload the files.
It will take less than 10 minutes to setup.